# Error, when using ELKIs data generator

Tags: terminal, elki

Maybe it is because of my skills in handling the terminal, but I don't understand why I get an exception here. 
I have extracted the folders. And I think the paths are right.

```
  db@computer:~/Desktop/elki-0.7.0~20150828/elki$ java -cp elki-0.7.0~20150828.jar de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.GeneratorXMLSpec -app.out 0.txt -bymodel.spec 1.xml
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/trove/list/TIntList
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.trove.list.TIntList
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
    db@computer:~/Desktop/elki-0.7.0~20150828/elki$
```

Comment: Try `-jar` instead of `-cp`? Java is supposed to load the dependencies then. Also try the `elki.sh` script included.

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry for not taking the question down. I had to build trove with ant. And then it worked:
java -cp ~/somefolders/elki-0.7.0~20150828.jar:/home/somefolders/3.1a1/output/lib/trove-150915135840.jar de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.GeneratorXMLSpec -app.out 0.txt -bymodel.spec mouse.xml

Comment: Maven should download trove automatically, and the "complete package" download on the web page does include all dependencies, including Trove and the Batik libraries for SVG graphics, in the folder `dependency`. Building trove yourself is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java **classpath** is incomplete.

Specifically, it does not include the Trove library required.